# I am getting Range error like Invalid value: Not in range 16..17, inclusive: 19Error: RangeError (end):

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using Dart pad for to show the list items using sublist but i am getting range error here is my code please help me.

```
void main() {
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q','f','e','y'];

  for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if(i.isEven && i<list.length-1)
      print(list.sublist(i,i+2)); 
    else 
      print(list.sublist(i,i+3));
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to access `i + 3` which is outside the list.

Comment: but i want 3 items please help me for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried accessing some items outside the list with `i + 3`. Using `i<list.length-2` will allow the compiler to check if the item is in the list before trying to print the value.

```dart
void main() {
  var list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q'];

  for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++) {
    if(i.isEven && i<list.length-2)
      print(list.sublist(i,i+2));
    else if(i<list.length-2)
      print(list.sublist(i, i+3));
  }
}
```

Comment: One problem sir the last item is not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217008/discussion-between-pranay-bhaturkar-and-jideguru).